# jquery loop conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, musicbrainz

How do I write a conditional statement for a jquery $.each loop?  I tried to follow the suggestions at [Is there conditional looping with $.each function in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984962/is-there-conditional-looping-with-each-function-in-jquery) and other posts, however, I couldn't get it to work:

```
$.each((rgJson1["release-groups"]), function(index, item) {  

var workTitle = item.title;
var pType = item['primary-type'];
var frDate = item['first-release-date'];

if (pType = "Album") {

console.log(workTitle);

}

});
```

When I tried that, it set the pType variable to "Album".  So, I tried:

```
if (item['primary-type'] = "Album") {

console.log(item.title);
```

But it still didn't work.  I also tried a variety of different combinations of brackets, quotes, and the like, but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
if (item['primary-type'] === "Album")
```

or

```
if (pType === "Album")
```

using just a single '=' will set the value, using '===' will check for congruency