# How to loop multiple images and display them in different divs with watermark on the images?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm trying to loop multiple images in a div called **center** the image is supposed to be in the div watermarked

Here's my code when looping the images in div **center**:

```
@foreach($data as $key)

    <div id="center">
        $image_file = $key->album['0']->image;
    </div>

@endforeach
```

The codes when inserting a watermark on the image to be diplayed in the div **center**:

```
var image_file = '<?php echo asset($image_file) ?>';
                                watermark([image_file, 'http://localhost:8080/uploads/product/watermark.jpg'])
                                    .image(watermark.image.center(0.5))
                                    .then(function (img) {
                                        document.getElementById("center").appendChild(img);
                                    });
```

but when i do that, all the images come in the same div **center**, instead of being multiple images in multiple **center** divs

Here is a screenshot of how it is diplayed **versus** how it should be displayed[image]

**How it should be diplayed(picture with its respective details)**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: You are giving the same id to the a div that is rendered multiple times, generate a dynamic id or use a class

Comment: I tried to use a class but it doesn't work either!

Comment: make an ajax call, and loop using jquery/javascript [here is an example to loop with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984962/is-there-conditional-looping-with-each-function-in-jquery)

Comment: @fatman i generated a dynamic id and it worked, thank you for the help!